# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO

Tags: php, syntax

I am receiving the this error

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO"

with the following php code. I've checked brackets and quotes but I can't seem to find it.

```
<?php
if(!$_GET['ae']):
    _e('<a href="'.echo get_permalink(icl_object_id(9132, 'page', true)).'" class="row">foo</a>');
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Remove the `echo` to start with.

Comment: `_e` funtion already echoes it, just concatenate the string, no need for that extra echo

Comment: remove `echo`. not needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `_e` function already echoes things,so no need for that extra `echo`

```
<?php
if(!$_GET['ae']):
    _e('<a href="'.get_permalink(icl_object_id(9132, 'page', true)).'" class="row">foo</a>');
endif;
?>
```